# Feeding Units of Fish to Fussy Toffs

Tags: lateral-thinking, science

**Farthingbottom School** is an elite establishment catering for the educational needs of an international group of students from noteworthy families. They have had complaints from some parents that the school dinners are not very healthy, more specifically that there is not enough fish on offer. As a result, the Headmaster has brought in a menu consultant to determine some suitable options.

The consultant sent out a questionnaire asking the pupils to indicate their preference for the following four options: 'Anchovies', 'mackerel', 'kedgeree', and 'salmon' on the following rating scale:

```
+4 Worship
+3 Adore
+2 Love
+1 Like
-1 Dislike
-2 Hate
-3 Detest
-4 Abhorr
```

These are the responses he got back:

> **Anchovies**
>   *Love*: Eldred-Campbell
>   *Like*: Ella-Charlotte
>   *Dislike*: Eloise-Florence; Magnus-Ford-Stephen; Marc-Frances
>
> **mackerel**
>   *Love*: Enrico; Portia; Eloise-Florence; Marc-Frances
>   *Like*: Felix
>   *Dislike*: Primula
>   *Hate*: Eldred-Campbell
>
> **salmon**
>   *Worship*: Eldred-Campbell
>   *Like*: Ella-Charlotte
>   *Dislike*: Randolph
>   *Hate*: Felix; Primula; Enrico; Marc-Frances; Magnus-Ford-Stephen
>   *Detest*: Portia; Eloise-Florence
>
> **kedgeree**
>   *Like*: Felix; Primula; Enrico; Portia; Eloise-Florence; Marc-Frances; Magnus-Ford-Stephen
>   *Dislike*: Eldred-Campbell

It was clear that serving kedgeree was going to suit the most children, however the headmaster anticipated that he would receive a backlash from Eldred-Campbell's parents. So he decided to write a letter to them.

**Question:**
What was their surname?

**Bonus:**
What were all the children's surnames?

**Hint 1**

> The name of the school is completely irrelevant.

**Hint 2**

> The rating system is powerful

**Hint 3**

> What would this puzzle be about if there was a lack of fish?

Comment: Um.... Campbell?

Comment: @Anachor No he had a hyphenated first name.

Comment: Eldred-Campbell's surname was Salmon, obviously. His father used to be the leader of the Scottish National Party.

Comment: Is it intentional that Marc-Frances both likes and hates Salmon?

Comment: @user1618143 No, that is completely unintentional. I'll fix it shortly.

Comment: Is there significance in the fact that Anchovies is capitalized but the other fish are not?

Comment: @VictorHenry Yes

Comment: Maybe Anchovies is someone's name if it's capitalized?

Comment: @GordonK Do some kids have the same surname?

Comment: Is it something to do with the periodic table?

Comment: @LuxxMiner No, they all have different names.

Comment: @Randalthor Nothing to do with the periodic table.

Comment: @GordonK One last question: Do the surnames necessarily have to be a "normal surname" (like Smith, Brown, Johnson, etc..)? Or are they more like "weird/very unusual surnames" (Ostrichhunter, Gravitylover, Octagonface, etc...)?

Comment: @LuxxMiner The surnames are well-known surnames. Not as common as Smith, Brown, etc but I'm pretty sure you'll be familiar with all of them.

Comment: Is a given child's first name meaningful in determining their surname?

Comment: @Vicky The child's surname can be determined from their preferences alone. The first name helps confirm the surname, but in Randolph's case distinguishes between a couple of possibilities.

Comment: @Vicky I would be amazed if anyone could get the surnames based entirely or primarily on the first names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that:

> the names of the fish are references to SI units:
>  Anchovies => Amp
>  mackerel => meter
>  salmon => second
>  kedgeree => kilogram

So Eldred-Campbell's surname is:

> an SI derived unit made up of Amps^2, meters^-2, seconds^4, kilograms^-1... that would be **Farad** and his initials E-C hint towards **Electrical Capacitance**.

For the bonus question:

> Ella-Charlotte: A^1 s^1 **Coulomb** (Electrical Charge)
>  Eloise-Florence: A^-1 m^2 s^-3 k^1 **Volt** (Electromotive Force)
>  Magnus-Ford-Stephen: A^-1 s^-2 k^1 **Tesla** (Magnetic Field Strength)
>  Marc-Frances: A^-2 m^2 s^-2 k^1  **Weber** (Magnetic Flux) *(Wikipedia says this is kg⋅m2⋅s−2⋅A−1 so I think Marc Frances should merely dislike, rather than hate, Anchovies)*
>  Enrico: m^2 s^-2 k^1 **Joule** (Energy)
>  Portia: m^2 s^-3 k^1 **Watt** (Power)
>  Felix: m^1 s^-2 k^1 **Newton** (Force)
>  Primula: m^-1 s^-2 k^1 **Pascal** (Pressure)
>  Randolph: s-1 **Becquerel** (Radioactivity)

This was a great puzzle. Thank goodness for

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_derived_unit :-)
>  P.S. The school should have been called the Seafood Institute!

Comment: Congratulations. 99% of the way there. I was after the family name, rather than the name used for the derived unit - it's the same thing in most cases, but a couple are slightly longer. Apologies for the error on magnetic flux, I'll edit the question to correct this.

Comment: Oh, you mean like Volta instead of Volt? That makes sense.

Comment: That's wonderful :-) I just don't get Hint 3 at all.

Comment: @VašekPotoček What does it say if you leave "of Fish" out of the title?

Comment: @Vicky: and Farad would be Faraday.

Comment: I was expecting Faraday and Volta, but I'll mark this as accepted.